# Getting Login item details

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to get a list of Login items on mac...

```
UInt32 seed = 0U;
LSSharedFileListRef loginItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);
NSArray *currentLoginItems = (__bridge NSArray *)(LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(loginItems, &seed));
for(NSString *login in currentLoginItems){

const char *cString = [login UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"%s", Cstring);

}
```

I am trying to parse this string to get login items name. But for any operation on "login" String i am getting error like:

> [__NSCFType UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6000000e9d00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working with the LSSharedFileList library and i got this function that might help you.

```
-(NSArray *)GetLoginItems{

  NSMutableArray *myStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
  CFStringRef LoginItemName = nil;

 // Get Login Items
  LSSharedFileListRef loginItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);

  if (loginItems) {

    NSArray *loginItemsArray = (__bridge NSArray *)LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(loginItems, nil);

    for (int i = 0; i < [loginItemsArray count]; i++) {

        LSSharedFileListItemRef currentItemRef = (__bridge LSSharedFileListItemRef)[loginItemsArray objectAtIndex:i];

        // Gets Items Display Name
        LoginItemName = LSSharedFileListItemCopyDisplayName(currentItemRef);

        [myStrings addObject:(__bridge id _Nonnull)(LoginItemName)];
    }
  }

  CFRelease(loginItems);

  return myStrings;
}
```

This one is returning an array of strings but you can print them directly on the console. Hope it helps!